# Objective C: Remotely invalidate a timer

Tags: objective-c, ios, methods, timer

How do I invalidate a timer in one method when another method is called? Basically when `tapFig` is called, I want it to send a message to `moveStickFig` to invalidate the timer

```
-(void) moveStickFig:(NSTimer *)timer {
    UIButton *stick = (UIButton *)timer.userInfo;
    CGPoint oldPosition = stick.center;
    stick.center = CGPointMake(oldPosition.x + 1 , oldPosition.y);
    if (oldPosition.x == 900) {
        [stick removeFromSuperview];
        healthCount--;
        NSLog(@"%d", healthCount);
        [healthBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"health%d.png",healthCount]]];
    }
}

-(void) tapFig:(id)sender {
    UIButton *stick = (UIButton *)sender;
    count++;
    score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count];
    [stick removeFromSuperview];
    [stick release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a flag in `moveStickFig` that sets to true when `tapFig` is called.

```
-(void) moveStickFig:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    if( isTimerInvalidateSet )
    {
        [ self timer:invalidate ];
        return;
    }
    // ......
}

// you need to pass the same timer instance to `tapFig` that you earlier passed to `moveStickFig`.

-(void) tapFig:(id)sender
{
    isTimerInvalidateSet = true;
    [ self moveStickFig:theTimerInstance ] ; // theTimerInstance is same as earlier you passed to `moveStickFig`

    isTimerInvalidateSet = false;
    // ......
}
```

Note: Usually, you will set the timer to call a function repeatedly at a fixed frames per second. The timer does the job of calling it at that rate. There is no need of passing timer instance repeatedly. If that is what you want, then OK. `However, if you need your game logic to be continued, you need to reset the isTimerInvalidateSet to false.` Hope this helps !